# Change the UUID which the system selects for root partition

Tags: 20.04, fstab, grub-efi

After investigation, I realized the `UUID` of the root partition `/` was appearing at least  in 3 different locations:

1. `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg`
2. `/proc/cmdline`
3. `/etc/fstab`

How do I change the `UUID` which the system selects for root partition?

Comment: is there a reason you want to change the UUIDs?

Comment: @ThomasWard If I clone the partition with `dd` the UUID is also cloned to another partition

Comment: So, you have identical UUIDs then.  Why the change then to the UUID?  Changing the partition UUID can cause other problems, **ESPECIALLY** if you're using `dd` to do a clone.

Comment: @ThomasWard so if you have two partitions with exactly the same UUID, how do you select which is the root partition?

Comment: Maybe you need to start over and explain what you're trying to achieve.  The question as asked sounds like an incomplete question, and judging by your statement that's *also* the case that your use case here and needs are not documented, suggesting that it's missing details in the question about WHY you need to change UUID, etc.

Comment: @ThomasWard I edited my question. Imagine you clone a partition to another partition, then you change the UUID of the cloned partition. You have two partitions exactly equal except for their UUIDs. How do I change the `UUID` which the system selects for root partition?

Comment: @JoãoPimentelFerreira if you clone the root filesystem to another partition, and change the cloned filesystem's UUID, then you no longer have duplicate UUIDs.

Comment: @muru true, but image now, that I want the system to startup with cloned partition as root, after I changed its UUID

Comment: Change `fstab`, run `update-initramfs`, `update-grub`.

Comment: @muru, can you kindly be more verbose or give me some references? ;) I just need to change fstab mounting point and then run those 2 commands?

Comment: @muru, please add those steps as an answer for me to accept it :) thanks

Comment: I don't have a system on hand to test, but those should be enough. Check the generated grub config after running `update-grub` to confirm before rebooting.